# Immutable Objects & Updates

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, immutability

If I'm using an immutable class named `Name` that stores people's names, and someone wants to change their name shouldn't their name be updated (essentially delete the old entry and insert the new entry)? This appears to contradict the definition (by the annotation) of immutable as updating the entity will be ignored. What should I do if an immutable class stored in the database needs to be updated? Should it not be mapped as `@Immutable` even though it is an immutable class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference says:

> When an entity is read-only:
>
> - Hibernate **does not dirty-check the entity's simple properties** or
>     single-ended associations;
> - Hibernate will not update simple properties
>     or updatable single-ended associations;
> - Hibernate will not update the
>     version of the read-only entity if only simple properties or
>     single-ended updatable associations are changed;

And it also says:

> In some ways, Hibernate treats read-only entities the same as entities
>   that are not read-only:
>
> - Hibernate cascades operations to associations as defined in the entity
>     mapping.
> - Hibernate updates the version if the entity has a collection
>     with changes that dirties the entity;
> - **A read-only entity can be
>     deleted**.

So, I think that you have to delete() the instance and than save() it again with the new name yourself as the dirty-check will not happen on read-only entities.

Reference: [Read-only entities](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch12.html)